# Setting a custom zoom level in google maps

Tags: maps, zooming

I am using google maps api and would liken to get a zoom half way between two settings.  Is this possible and how would I go about it?

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Although `Mapview` workd internally with continuous zoom level variation (you can see it because in zoom animations, getProjection() is aligned with intermediate zoom levels), the API only makes available for selection integer zoom levels.

Regards.